# how to handle rest arguments and function in useeffect causing re-render

Tags: reactjs

say I have a function like this:

```
export const usePagedGetAll = <R, Args extends any[]>(
  baseUrl: string,
  ...args: Args
) => {
  const fn = useWrappedRemoteCall(
    async () => {
      return await fetchRequest<RemoteData<R>>(url, options);
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fn.execute(...args);
    })();
  }, [args, fn, paginationInfo.skip, paginationInfo.take]);

  return fn
};
```

The problem is that `args` is a new array each time so infinite re-render happens if it is in the deps array.  I do want it to re-render if an element changes.

same goes for the `fn` function, it is new each time so it will cause infinite re-render, what can I do.

I could stop the hooks eslint rule applying the fix

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fn.execute(...args);
    })();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [paginationInfo.skip, paginationInfo.take]);
```

but this seems like a common problem

Comment: Maybe you could use `useMemo` for `args` and `useCallback` for `fn` which would respectively have dependencies to update when required and add those as dependency for `useEffect`

Comment: same deal, I need it the memo to update when the args change and args is a new reference each time

Comment: You could maybe save it in a state then:  `const [derivedArgs, setDerivedArgs] = useState(args); useEffect(() => { /* compare element by element if args contains the same element as derivedArgs. If not, setDerivedArgs(args) */}, [args]); useEffect(() => {/* the hook from your question */}, [derivedArgs, fn, paginationInfo.skip, paginationInfo.take]])`.

Comment: Why is `fn` in the deps list? What does `args` array contain?

Comment: the eslint-plugin-react-hooks puts the deps there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your needs, I divide the dependency into two parts for analysis.

1. args

`args` is an array and will be brand new each time.

Consider creating a `useCustorCompareEffect`. By customizing the comparison function. The `effect` will actually be triggered only when the specified value changes.

[image: Edit useCustorCompareEffect Demo]

```js
const useCustorCompareEffect = (callback, value, compare) => {
  const prev = useRef({ init: true, value })
  useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = prev
    if (current.init) {
      callback()
      current.init = false
    } else {
      if (!compare || !compare(value, current.value)) {
        callback()
        current.value = value
      }
    }
  }, [callback, value, compare])
}

const useDemo=()=>{
  const compare = useCallback((curr, prev) => {
    // Compare functions, return comparison results, use `useCallback` to prevent triggering `effect` due to compare
  }, [])

  useCustorCompareEffect(
    () => {
      ...
    },
    [data],
    compare,
  )
}
```

2. fn

To use a function as a dependency, you can wrap the function definition in `useCallback` and then define the dependencies required by this function in `useCallback`.

```js
const execute = useCallback(() => {
  console.log('update')
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  execute()
}, [execute);
```

In your case, your function is obtained by another `useWrappedRemoteCall`, which needs to use the `useCallback` package `execute` definition in `useWrappedRemoteCall` and then return.
In addition, if you only use `execute` in `useEffect`, you need to extract `execute` and then use `execute` as a dependency. To prevent other data changes in fn from triggering `effect`

```js
const useWrappedRemoteCall = () => {
  const execute = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('update')
  }, [])
  return { execute }
}
const usePagedGetAll = () => {
  const { execute } = useWrappedRemoteCall()
  useEffect(() => {
    execute()
  }, [execute])
}
```

If there are other special circumstances, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` to write a custom hook which checks the `args` in-depth.

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  if(value != ref.current) {
    // ...
    // check if they are the same here else update ref.current
    // ...
    ref.current = value;
  }
  return ref.current;
}
```

Then wrap `useWrappedRemoteCall` function within `useMemo` as it returns an object.

```
const fn = React.useMemo(() => useWrappedRemoteCall(
  async () => {
    return await fetchRequest<RemoteData<R>>(url, options);
  }
), [url, options, fetchRequest]);
```

Final result:

```
export const usePagedGetAll = <R, Args extends any[]>(
  baseUrl: string,
  ...args: Args
) => {

  // use previous args if unmodified
  args = usePrevious(args);

  // useMemo to memoize the object returned by useWrappedRemoteCall
  const fn = React.useMemo(() => useWrappedRemoteCall(
    async () => {
      return await fetchRequest<RemoteData<R>>(url, options);
    }
  ), [url, options, fetchRequest]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fn.execute(...args);
    })();
  }, [args, fn, paginationInfo.skip, paginationInfo.take]);

  return fn
};
```